# Multiline/innerHtml/contentEditable Angular Challenge

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to make with Angular5 a sort of "text-editor" with **div** and **contenteditable** property,so the user can write plain text, but also that lets the user select part of random text and then trigger an event that add a **div** tag with some classes and **ID**, all surrounding the selected text, because the user then can add some other properties to this recent selected text.

However the user don't have to see the tags, only the result of the suroundings html tags, and then I want to save the whole string with its html properties. This is because, later, the user can call again this "*template*" and I have to show all the settings that the user made.

I've tried [innerHtml], but this property writes backwards and I can do multiline div.

This is the simplified version of the HTML with the **appContentEditableModel** that leaves me to use it as an equivalent to **ngModel**.

The **(click)** method I'm not using it, until I can find a way to add all this things in the string

```
<div *ngFor="let item_drag of items_drag; let idx = index">
    <div [(appContenteditableModel)]="item_drag.data.content" 
         contenteditable="true"
         (mouseup)="setSelectedVariableText(item_drag)"
          style="min-width:100px; max-width: 599px; padding: 2px 0;border: 1px dashed gray; cursor: text; white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>
    </div>
```

This is the object where I save the data

```
items_drag = [
  {data:{
      type: 'whatEver,
      content: 'string'
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sanitize the code in order to 'execute' as html.

This can help,
https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

Though it is not advised to to use that without any manual sanity check. Your code could be vulnerable of XSS.